# How to delete protected pictures on a D-90 Nikon?

Tags: nikon-d90, delete

Somehow I ended up with two photos protected on my camera memory and they won't delete.

How can I unprotect the images on a Nikon D-90?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While viewing protected images on your Nikon D-90 press White Balance/Key button and this will unprotect them. I had the same problem but don't know how I managed to "protect" them in the first place..lol. :))

Answer (score 5):

Either format the card with the format function from the menus, or browse the photos and press the `key` button to unlock the photos, then erase them.

Comment: Was trying to avoid a format, since I imagine that is not good for the card if you do it repeatedly and I might reach this condition again.

Comment: @William KF - Format often.  I format every time the card goes in the camera.

Comment: Yep, just format it every time you manipulate with the card like switching it from one device to another. It's a fast format which only rewrites the TOC, it's not a low level format, so don't worry, the card won't be destroyed :)

Comment: rfusca is correct, formatting the card is actually better than deleting the pictures.  Remember the retention of your pictures is way more important than the memory card and memory cards DO wear out over time so formatting it after every use ensures any bad sectors have been checked and marked as bad before next use.

Comment: @WilliamKF: I can tell you this: I work professionally as a photographer and I have CF cards I still use regularly that are more than 5 years old... Now I format each and every card with the camera I'll be using it on before I start a new session, I do somewhere in the neighborhood of 150 photo sessions per year of various types, so... Conservatively I can say that some of my cards have been through 500 formats- probably more. With all of that I have never had a card die on me... The moral of the story is: format early, format often.

Comment: @BarrySemple I wonder about the bad sector marking - if the camera is doing a quick format where it's only overwriting the table of contents, how does it know what sectors are bad?

Comment: @Evan, @Barry — all of that is happening at a level below what the filesystem is aware of. Formatting won't change that. But I agree with @Jay that it also won't hurt, because (except for very cheap cards, perhaps) this is exactly the scenario that the card's wear-leveling code is designed to deal with — it won't write the FAT to the same physical block over and over again. That leaves you a lot of format cycles.

Comment: I too format my CF card before every photographic outing.  I have never had any problems.  All I would say is make sure to use the in-Camera formatting option (A menu option on Canon DSLR's, I think a button combo on Nikon?).  Do not format the card from Windows or a Mac whilst it is in a card-reader attached to the computer.  I believe they use a different filesystem? Or don't put something back in place that the camera needs?  (Not sure).